# Proving G is 3 edge connected if G is connected graph and for every edge $e$, there are cycles $C_1$ and $C_2$ s.t. $E(C_1) \bigcap E(C_2) = \{e\}$

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness

(1) If G is connected graph, and for every edge $e$, there are cycles $C_1$ and $C_2$ such that $E(C_1) \bigcap E(C_2) = \{e\},$ then $G$ is 3 edge connected.

I'm trying to figure out how to prove this statement. Not sure how. I've been told that it suffices to show that no set of two edges disconnects $G$.

My question is why? Why does showing that no set of two edges disconnects $G$ prove (1)?

Comment: The definition of $3$-edge connectivity is simply that at least $3$ edges have to be deleted to disconnect the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any edge $e$ of the graph. Denote the vertices connected by this edge $u$ and $v$.

Since $e\ = \ u-v\ $ is in two cylces, there are two disjoint paths from $u$ to $v$ not
 using the edge $e$ forming a cycle. Denote it by $C$. In particular, there is still
 a path between the vertices $u$ and $v$.

Delete a second edge.
 If it is in $C$, then the graph remains connected because in a cycle there are always
 two paths between two vertices.

If it is not in $C$, then you can use the argument for the first edge again.

Comment: What is the argument for the first edge again?

Comment: It is the argument that the two cycles can be merged into a single cycle after the edge is deleted.